# How to replace Roboto with a font that I downloaded

Tags: materialize

I've already put my downloaded Montserrat font-pack inside my public/dist/fonts/ directory, how will I replace Roboto as my font.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your font, you would need to put the css that changes the original font after the materialize css file in your html

```
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
```

if it doesn't work, just simply add `!important` at the end, it will be working.